# How to make date picker appear on button click as date picker is in top bar of view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker

As I put date picker in top bar of the controller as well as the tool bar too, to save the space on the view controller for clarity.

But, what should I do, so that picker view will appear with toolbar on button click and disappear on button click.

Refer below mentioned image for more details.
[image]

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Is this question is visible to everyone??

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You can use the datepicker on textfield, as text field have a default property inputAccessoryView so use my code:

```
txtFieldCustom.inputView = datePicker           //To make appearence of date picker
txtFieldCustom.inputAccessoryView = toolBar     //To make appearence of toolbar
```

Comment: the question is `on button click` not `textfield` didn't help the people who are searching for the correct answer at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
func createDatePicker() {

    self.datepicker.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 400, width:self.view.frame.size.width, height: 200)
    self.view.addSubview(datepicker)
}

@IBAction func buttonclicked() {
    self.createDatePicker()
}
```